# How to insert data at the end of appointment body in outlook add-in?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am trying to add some html to the end of the appointment body. I found `setSelectedDataAsync` to insert at current cursor position and `prependAsync` to insert in the beginning of appointment through task pane but nothing for inserting at the end. Is there a way to insert to the end of appointment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this feature is not a part of the product. As a workaround, you can get the body text from the appointment, add the extra text, and then set the body of the appointment. This is not a great workaround, however, it may be decent for your scenario.

If this workaround is insufficient, there's already a feature request on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/35104888-request-for-a-body-appendasync-method) for appending text to the body of a message or appointment. Please upvote this request if you haven't done so already. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thanks this workaround worked for me, but I still upvoted the feature as this may not be a one fit for all solution.